# SQL Select help - who paid this year but is inactive

Tags: sql, sql-server, select

I have a table with costumers that are active or inactive.
The inactive is the ones who are more then 1 year without any payment. I need to know how many inactive became active the first semester of this year.

I only have a table with: "costumer id, amount paid, date paid, status"

I'm trying something like that:

```
select DISTINCT COSTUMER_ID 
from finance 
where (DATEPAID >= '2014-01-01' 
    and DATEPAID < '2014-07-01') 
and COSTUMER_ID in (
    select COSTUMER_ID 
    from finance 
    where DATEPAID < '2013-07-01'
)
```

First part is to see who paid this year, the second, who paid at least once in its life. But can't continue. Any help?

Sample data:

```
costumer_id amount paid date paid    todaystatus
  1         50        2012-02-03       inactive
  1         75        2013-02-03       inactive
  2         10        2013-01-02       active
  2         12        2014-04-02       active
  3         65        2014-06-02       active
  4         10        2011-01-06       active
  4         30        2014-04-16       active
```

The costumer 2 and 4 is the one I want. The 2 became inactive in 2014-01-02 but reactivated in 2014-04-02
The 4 became inactive in 2012-01-06 but reactivated in 2014-04-16

The output can be a list of costumer_id

Thanks

Comment: the "and costumer_id in (......)" seems to be completely redundant when compared to the "and datepaid < '2014-07-01' from the line above it.  Was there a reason for this I'm not seeing?

Comment: If the costumer paid between 2013-07-01 and 2013-12-31 it was not inactive, because less then 1 year has passed.
I need just inactive that paid this year. Don't mind when it became inactive.
The costumer can be inactive for more then 2 years, or became inactive 2014-06-01 but reactivated 2014-06-02 ,whatever.

Comment: You want only in active details or active details also?

Comment: Need to know the number: how many costumers that were inactive became active this year. I'm at my job and have to do this analysis.

Comment: could you give some post some sample data? and required output your query seems wrong!

Comment: Just edited with a sample.
The output can be a list of costumer_id

Comment: A "Customer" is someone who buys goods or services. A "Costumer" is someone who makes fancy outfits.

Comment: Sorry about that. My mistake! English is not my first language.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this, and add some data samples in SQLfiddle to tune this query.

```
select DISTINCT f1.COSTUMER_ID 
from finance f1
where (DATEPAID >= '2014-01-01' 
    and DATEPAID < '2014-07-01') 
and datediff(d, (
    select top 1 f2.DATEPAID
    from finance  f2
    where DATEPAID <> f1.DATEPAID
    and f1.COSTUMER_ID=f2.COSTUMER_ID
    order by f2.DATEPAID desc)
    ,f1.DATEPAID)>365
```

Comment: Ooh, I like this better than my first answer. Much easier. I'm working on an edit showing how to use LAG, though, that will be better still (if he has sql server 2012).

Answer (score 0):

You want to look at the maximum of the date paid for customers who are currently inactive.  This seems to implement your business rules:

```
select CUSTUMER_ID, max(DATEPAID) as maxdp
from finance 
group by CUSTUMER_ID
having maxdp < '2013-07-01';
```

Note that I changed `COSTOMERID` to `CUSTOMERID`, which is the better spelling in English.

Answer (score 0):

If you define "inactive" this way:

> The inactive is the ones who are more then 1 year without any payment.

And you want to know:

> how many inactive became active the first semester of this year

The only way to answer that question is if the finance table is storing every transaction, and not merely the balance. If that is what's happening, and based on the sample data, the query looks like this:

```
SELECT f1.CustomerID
FROM Finance f1
INNER JOIN Finance f2 
     ON f2.CustomerID = f1.CustomerID 
         AND f2.DatePaid = 
               (
                  SELECT TOP 1 DatePaid 
                  FROM Finance f
                  WHERE f.CustomerID = f1.CustomerID and f1.DatePaid < f1.DatePaid
                  ORDER BY DatePaid DESC
                )
          AND f2.DatePaid <= DATEADD(year, -1, f1.DatePaid
WHERE f1.DatePaid >= '2014-01-01' and f1.DatePaid < '2014-07-01'
```

The trick is the join the table to itself, so that you have in one record both the current transaction and prior transaction. Then you can easily select which records you want.

If you have Sql Server 2012, you can use the [new LAG keyword](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh231256.aspx) to make this *much* simpler, and probably faster:

```
SELECT CustomerID
FROM Finance
WHERE DatePaid >= '2014-01-01' and DatePaid < '2014-07-01'
    AND DATEADD(year, -1, DatePaid) > LAG(DateAdd) 
                                      OVER (PARTITION BY CustomerID 
                                            ORDER BY CustomerID, DatePaid DESC)
ORDER BY CustomerID
```